# Random LightGBM Forest

Tags: ensemble-modeling, lightgbm, gradient-boosting-decision-trees, bagging

I'm not completly sure about the bias/variance of boosted decision trees (LightGBM especially), thus I wonder if we generally would expect a performance boost by creating an ensemble of multiple LightGBM models, just like with Random Forest?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can tune a GBM to accomplish a good bias/variance tradeoff by itself.  You could try to set the hyperparameters of the GBM to overfit, and then bag those, but in most situations I wouldn't expect much/any gain over a better-tuned single GBM.

Somewhat related: Microsoft's `InterpretML` package implements [their version of](https://interpret.ml/docs/ebm.html) a GA2M model, involving several layers of bagging and boosting.  There the point is to produce something more interpretable, so the boosting happens on only one or two features at a time (but in a cyclic fashion, so it's not totally independent).